# How to interpret coefficients and intercepts of logistic regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, coefficients

I am running Iris data set... I have four features and one target 
variable. I am getting only three intercepts instead of four and 
please coef_ in this case.

The code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr=LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(train_x,train_y)
```

The results:

```
    lr.coef_
    output-
    array([[ 0.37158254,  1.35098324, -2.09936396, -0.93263471],
       [ 0.46758048, -1.57259888,  0.39692171, -1.0678223 ],
       [-1.52865509, -1.43245908,  2.30484329,  2.08586834]])

   lr.intercept_
   output-
   array([ 0.23818179,  1.0298293 , -1.04654308])
```

Answer (score 1):

Intercepts depend on the number of classes, not the number of features.
See the doc [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html).

The Iris data set has 3 classes according to the [official documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html).

Therefore, everything seems fine to me.

The intercepts are biases that are added to the decision function. You can set `fit_intercept` to `False` to see how the classification results vary with and without intercepts.